# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available for static method

Tags: java, junit, powermock, easymock

im new to junit mocking. and im trying to mock below line.

```
IsomeInterface someinterface = someClass.getInstance();
```

where `someClass` is implementation of `IsomeInterface`.
and `getInstance` is a static method which returns `someClass` object.
below is the mocking i tried.

```
someClass someClassMock= PowerMock.createMock(someClass.class);
EasyMock.expect(someClass.getInstance()).andReturn(someClassMock);
```

exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControlForLastCall(EasyMock.java:560)
    at org.easymock.EasyMock.expect(EasyMock.java:538)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)
```

to mock all methods of this class.

Also there can be a problem in constructing mock via powermock and verify them by easymock so try:

```
   PowerMock.expectNew(NewInstanceClass.class).andReturn(mockObject)
```